# GPIO odd behaviour

Tags: gpio, python

I am on RPi 2, using Python 2.7.3 with Raspbian straight off the micro SD card which shipped with my machine. I have a program which did not behave as anticipated. So, I have isolated the following small code fragment which displays
the unexpected behaviour. In this version, I have GPIO pins 14 and 15 currently
connected to a 50m cable, which is not attached to anything and the two lines
are open-circuit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import smtplib

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# Define which GPIO pin to use
testPin = 14
switch = 15

# Set 14 and 15 as (resp.) output and input and set initial voltages (logic     different in each case)
GPIO.setup(testPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
GPIO.setup(switch, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

print GPIO.input(switch)

GPIO.output(testPin, 1)
print GPIO.input(switch)
time.sleep(1.0)

GPIO.cleanup()

# Normal python exit
raise SystemExit
```

The second `print` statement consistently gives 1, which seems wrong to me. If I instead move the `time.sleep(1.0)` up one line to rest before the second `print` statement, that `print` consistently gives 0 (which seems good to me). Why does my output depend on where the `sleep` command goes?

Comment: The details appear incomplete.  Do we assume you have connected GPIOs 14 and 15?

Comment: what are pins 14 and 15 connected to?

Comment: My apologies. 14 and 15 are currently open circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any pull-up/downs on those lines other than the weak internal one?

I'm just thinking about all that Mains Hum and other transient voltages being induced in those "[transmission lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line)" which will be picking up all sorts of things, especially if the other ends are floating.

If you are going to be doing things with long cables you also really want to have some sort of buffer between those wires and the naked pins of the CPU which is pretty much what the GPIO connections are!  "Line drivers" for outputs and input "buffers/receivers" for inputs.

The significance of such long cables is that they add capacitance to the ideal, theoretical circuit.  It takes time for an electric charge (i.e. quantity of electrons) to flow (current) into or out of such capacitance and through the resistance of the wire so for a "step" change in potential difference at one end, there is a delay as the voltage changes down the line to reach a stable value at the other end.  So, despite the circuit being "open" there is in fact some distributed capacitance and resistance on as long cable that slows down the changes at the GPIO pin terminal.